# How to replace date part to current date in existing date object

Tags: java, android, date, time

I have a date object parsed from JSON in the follwing format:

```
String date = getJsonDateFromServer(); 
Date result = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ").parse(date);
```

But I am only interested in the time part (no months, year, day etc).
So my question is: How do I replace the date part (Months, Year, Day) correctly without loosing the time zone information?

What I finally want to do is the following:

(1) Parsing two dates (without date information). Start and Endtime

(2) Check for another date 'dw' (with date information) if 'dw' is in between the time defined in start and end from (1)

For example:

```
Date start = parse(18:00 +02:00);
Date end = parse(20:00 +02:00);
Date     dw=new Date();
boolean inBetween = dw>= start && dw <= end;
```

How to do this?

/UPDATE:
I implemented it for test purposes this way:

```
public boolean isActiveOn(Date date) {

    Calendar toCheck = Calendar.getInstance();
    toCheck.setTime(date);

    Calendar cal_start = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal_start.setTime(this.time_begin);
    cal_start.set(toCheck.get(Calendar.YEAR), toCheck.get(Calendar.MONTH),
            toCheck.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));

    Calendar cal_end = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal_end.setTime(this.time_end);
    cal_end.set(toCheck.get(Calendar.YEAR), toCheck.get(Calendar.MONTH),
            toCheck.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));

    boolean after_start = toCheck.after(cal_start);
    boolean before_end = toCheck.before(cal_end);
    return after_start && before_end;
}
```

But isn't that causing problems when different timezones are set in this.time_begin, this.time_end and date ?

Comment: If you could possibly use Joda Time, it would make your life a lot simpler...

Comment: I am developing for android, Joda seems to to work well on the phones?! And how would you do that there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you have to do is:

```
String date = getJsonDateFromServer(); 
Date result = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ").parse(date);

SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ssZ")
Date timeOnly = dateFormat.parse(dateFormat.format(result));
```

Now you have a date with time and timezone only.

And here is the compare code:

```
Date start = dateFormat.format(result);
Date end = dateFormat.format(resultNr2);
Date dw = dateFormat.format(resultNr3);
boolean inBetween = dw.after(start) && dw.before(end);
```

Comment: Problem here: DateFormat.format(Date) will return a String and no Date. But thanks... The only thing that could work is to parse it again `dateFormat.parse(dateFormat.format(date));`

Answer (score 0):

```
private DatePickerDialog createDialogWithoutDateField(){
             Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
             int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
             int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
             int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

(AdditionalRepaymentDetailClass.this, datePickerListener_edtToDate,mYear,mMonth, mDay);
             DatePickerDialog edtToDate= new DatePickerDialog(DirectDebitClass.this, datePickerListener_edtToDate, year, month,day);
        try{
            Field[] datePickerDialogFields = edtToDate.getClass().getDeclaredFields();
            for (Field datePickerDialogField : datePickerDialogFields) { 
                if (datePickerDialogField.getName().equals("mDatePicker")|| datePickerDialogField.getName().equals("mDaySpinner")) {
                    datePickerDialogField.setAccessible(true);
                    DatePicker datePicker = (DatePicker) datePickerDialogField.get(edtToDate);
                    Field datePickerFields[] = datePickerDialogField.getType().getDeclaredFields();
                    for (Field datePickerField : datePickerFields) {
                       if ("mDayPicker".equals(datePickerField.getName())|| "mDaySpinner".equals(datePickerField.getName())) {
                          datePickerField.setAccessible(true);
                          Object dayPicker = new Object();
                          dayPicker = datePickerField.get(datePicker);
                          ((View) dayPicker).setVisibility(View.GONE);

                       }
                    }
                 }

              }
            }catch(Exception ex){
            }

          return edtToDate;

        }
```

U can try this

Comment: Thanks, but I am loading the date from a server via Json. So its not a DatePicker problem...